# jQuery dynamic append SelectBOX to call PHP mysql Function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How to call PHP Function From jQuery

```
getstudent('"+$("#classroom").val()+"')
```

I sure MySQL had 4 records about `classroomid='c1'`

But I can't show 4 records to selectbox student

In HTML

```
<select  name="classroom" id="classroom" class="required"><option value="c1" selected>Room-1</option><option value="c2">Room-2</option></select>
```

In jQuery

```
$("#selectstudent").append("<tr><td><select name='student["+x+"]' id='student"+x+"'><?=getstudent('"+$("#classroom").val()+"')?></select>")</td></tr>").trigger('create');
```

In PHP

```
function getstudent($roomid){
  $query = "Select studentid,studentname From student Where classroomid='$roomid' Order By studentid";
  $sql=mysql_query($query);
  if (mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    while ($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
      $str = $str."<option value='".$rs["studentid"]."'>".$rs["studentname"]."</option>";
    }
  }else{
    $str="";
  }
  //test//
  $str = $str."<option value=''>".$query."</option>";
  $str = $str."<option value=''>".mysql_num_rows($sql)."</option>";
  return $str;
}
```

I only got "`Select studentid,studentname From student Where classroomid='c1' Order By studentid`" And "0" in selectbox student

If I delete "`Where classroomid='$roomid'`" from $query，It can show all data into selectbox student

I paste "`Select studentid,studentname From student Where classroomid='c1' Order By studentid`" to querywindow of phpMyAdmin and run，It's show 4 records

Comment: To call php function from jQuery you should use jQuery.ajax() .
In jQuery ajax your action url will be php file where you can retrieve the records from the database .Return the records from php and get the data in response of jQuery.ajax().In jquery you should append the rows.